# Argument of type '(address: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Suite) => void'

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat, defi, typescript

I'm trying to implement the pancakeswap router functions. I've forked the mainnet with hardhat and then tried to receive the addresses with typescript. I'm using the typescript for the first time and so, It feels difficult to understand. Well, after generating the typechain of the contract...

```
import type { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/dist/src/signer-with-address";
import { artifacts, ethers, waffle } from "hardhat";
import type { Artifact } from "hardhat/types";
import { expect } from "chai";
import hre from 'hardhat';

import type { PancakeSwapping } from "../../typechain/contracts/Pancakeswap.sol/PancakeSwapping";
import { Signers } from "../types";

let Pancakeswap;
let pancakeswap;

beforeEach(async function(){
  Pancakeswap = await ethers.getContractFactory("PancakeSwapping");
  pancakeswap = Pancakeswap.deploy();
  console.log(`pancakeswap address>>>>${(await pancakeswap).address}`);
});

describe("Unit testing pancakeswap functions", (address: any)=>{ //getting error here

});
```

Actually, I've had no idea of how to use the addresses after forking mainnet, and so I took a guide from [here](https://mixbytes.io/blog/how-fork-mainnet-testing)
After seeing it, I'm trying to receive the given addresses like below...

```
describe("Unit testing pancakeswap functions", (address: any)=>{ //getting error here
    
    });
```

and the error says...

```
Argument of type '(address: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Suite) => void'.ts(2345)
```

your help will literally help me to learn the mechanism of interacting with smartcontracts using typescript.